# Customized newsletter

Tags: feature-request, newsletter

Being a mathematics website, the questions asked here are on pretty diverse areas. However, the weekly newsletter is the same for everyone.

I believe that being able to receive customized newsletters, i.e., receiving the most popular Q/A of the web *in one's favorite categories/tags* would be fairly interesting.

What is more, since the website has a high question/day rate, we wouldn't face too many 'empty newsletters' problems.

What do you think ? Is this doable ?

Comment: Related: [Can newsletters take into account a user's favorite tags on that site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110902/can-newsletters-take-into-account-a-users-favorite-tags-on-that-site)